# Добавление PUSH-уведомлений

Tags: предложение, уведомления

Предлагаю добавить на ruSO push-уведомления. Это было бы удобно. Например, ждешь ответа на вопрос и не приходится каждые 5-10 минут заходить на stack overflow, просто приходит уведомление.

Также не совсем по теме вопроса, но можно было бы добавить следующую фичу: когда приходит входящее сообщение - мигать title`ом. Так, находясь на другой вкладке, можно было бы сразу узнать, что случилось что-то важное (или не совсем).

Comment: В этом качестве можно мобильное приложение использовать - оно уведомления шлёт

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы правы, но все же хотелось бы и на ПК

Comment: API у сайта есть, я его сегодня проверял, оно работает. По идее можно за неделю другую вечерами соорудить плагин для хрома, который бы раз в n времени делал запросы и выводил сообщения. Сам бы сделал, но вот во фронте и особенно плагинах - не силён) Да и времени особо нет)

Comment: Посмотрите варианты здесь: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47750/stack-overflow-desktop-notifier